# Why does Tinymce fails to initiate once jquery dialog box is closed and reopened?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tinymce, jquery-dialog

I have a jquery UI dialog box with tinymce inside of it, the first time I open the dialog box tinymce works fine but once I close the dialog box and reopen it I see the tinymce editor but I can't type anything inside as if it is disabled.

Comment: Please include your code ... my crystal ball is playing up today ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the problem by delaying the function:

```
setTimeout(function() {

g = {};

g.oEditor = new tinymce.Editor (
    "notesComments",
    {
        // General options
        mode : "none",
        theme : "advanced",
        height : 350,
        plugins : "style,layer,table,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template",

        // Theme options
        theme_advanced_buttons1 : "newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull",
        theme_advanced_buttons2 : "formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
        theme_advanced_buttons3 : "undo,redo,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen|,nonbreaking,pagebreak,hr",
        theme_advanced_buttons4 : "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote",
        theme_advanced_buttons5 : "link,unlink,image,cleanup,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
        theme_advanced_buttons6 : "tablecontrols,|,removeformat,visualaid",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
        theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
        theme_advanced_resizing : false
    });

g.oEditor.render();

}, 3000);
```

Comment: in this case you should use a document ready function to avoid to delay the initalization to much! see my edit answer

Answer (score 1):

Problem looks to  be pretty clear here. You did not shut down the tinymce instance correctly when closing the jQuery dialogue box.

To shut down an edtor instance use:

```
tinymce.execCommand('mceRemoveControl',true,'editor_id');
```

**Update:** You should use a document.ready - function to not delay the editor initialization to much (in case the document is loaded after 1,4 seconds - you spoil 1,6 seconds and keep the user waiting):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  g = {};

  g.oEditor = new tinymce.Editor (
    "notesComments",
    {
        // General options
        mode : "none",
        theme : "advanced",
        height : 350,
        plugins : "style,layer,table,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template",

        // Theme options
        theme_advanced_buttons1 : "newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull",
        theme_advanced_buttons2 : "formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
        theme_advanced_buttons3 : "undo,redo,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen|,nonbreaking,pagebreak,hr",
        theme_advanced_buttons4 :   "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote",
        theme_advanced_buttons5 :   "link,unlink,image,cleanup,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
        theme_advanced_buttons6 : "tablecontrols,|,removeformat,visualaid",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
        theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
        theme_advanced_resizing : false
    });

  g.oEditor.render();


});
```

Comment: I added this to my beforeclose function and it still doesn't work

Comment: Yes I did that, I think there is something to do with DOM not being ready fast enough

Answer (score 0):

This one works like a charm:

```
if(tinyMCE.execCommand('mceRemoveEditor', false, 'editorId')) {
  // re-init..
}
```

I got this from [this thread](http://archive.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=34937)